# Request.UrlReferrer is coming as null on page refresh

Tags: javascript, c#, vb.net

Can anyone tell me how can I modifiy the code when refreshing the page value of Request. UrlReferrer is coming as null. Actually it is throwing an exception. I have to handle this exception. Any idea anyone?

Comment: Throwing an exception Object Refrence is not set to an instance of object.I have to handle this exception.

Comment: `modifiy the code` - line 37?

Comment: Exceptions are usually handled with `try/catch` - line 37?

Comment: The URL Referrer returns a value only when the user reaches the current page through a link from the previous page. Otherwise, document.referrer returns an empty string. The url referrer also returns an empty string if you have reached to that page from a secure site. To solve this, set a variable and use that when you reach that page.
`ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")` for the page and
`ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")` for the parameters sent.

Comment: How can I put this in try catch block??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`UrlReferrer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer(v=vs.110).aspx) can't be controlled by your server side code - it just exposes value sent by browser/client along with request. There are plenty of cases that value is not present (initial request/refresh, HTTP/HTTPS transition) so your code must be able to handle this case.

At very least you just need to check for `null` (you may also need to handle `UriFormatException` if you need to handle requests from rogue clients in a nice way):

```
  if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
  {
       // run your code that deals with referrer
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution.But in my scenario its happening when i am trying to refresh the page and its showing null value.Checking Request.UrlReferrer != null will complete the work??I have tried even the solution you have given and its working but I am not sure what the impact it wil have on the rest of code.Any suggestions??

Comment: Referrer may be null. It is completely up to you how you decide to handle that case in your site.